# Can't Import using mysql command in java using ubuntu/Linux

Tags: java, mysql, database, ubuntu

I tried mysql restore command to restore from a text file in windows, it worked fine but when I run on ubuntu 14.4 it gives error.

Windows Command (works fine on windows but not on server/ubuntu)

```
String command = mysql + " --user=" + username + " --password=" + password + " -D " + database + " -e\"" + "source " + restoreFile + "\"";
```

I tried this command as well:

```
String restoreFile = "/home/chubby/test.sql";
String[] command = new String[]{ mysql, "--user=" + database, "--password=" + password, database, " -e", "source " + restoreFile };
```

code goes here:

```
String mysqldump = "/usr/bin/mysqldump"; 
String mysql = "/usr/bin/mysql"

Process process = null;
    try {           
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        int processComplete = process.waitFor();            
        if (processComplete == 0) {
            System.out.println("Database Restore is Successful!");              
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database Restore Failed!");             
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error occured");
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `--user` (mysql or mariaDB / linux). Try checking `mysql --help`

Comment: Also you quotes `"` look weird

Comment: Yeah! I used --user, It is format difference infact.

Comment: What's the value of `mysql` variable? My advice: just "craft" the command in a shell then transpose to you java code

Comment: Paths to the files: String mysqldump = "/usr/bin/mysqldump"; String mysql = "/usr/bin/mysql";

Comment: It worked under windows but when I deployed on server It failed, same is true for Mac

Comment: It would be interesting to know how it failed Do you get an exception? a permission denied? does the computer crash? What happens?

Comment: It goes into else condition, saying "Database Restore Failed"